# Another way of getting/requesting a Session Symfony2?

Tags: session, symfony, console, command, request

Is there any other way on how to request/get a session in symfony2? other than opening a service container and via request? thanks

I'm creating a session manager where it will create a session via command console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the session directly into your SessionManager:

<kbd>1</kbd> Create your session manager:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\YourBundle\Manager;

use Symfony\Component\Session/SessionInterface;

class SessionManager
{

    /**
     * The session
     *
     * @var SessionInterface
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @param SessionInterface
     */
    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }


}
```

<kbd>2</kbd> And declare it as a service:

```
services:
    # Session manager
    acme_your_bundle.session_manager:
        class: Acme\YourBundle\Manager\SessionManager
        arguments:
            session: "@session"
```

You can have a look at the api for the [Session](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html), it'll help you finishing up.